# Multipe parameters when defining react component as a function

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following code snippet

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When defining a component as a function, is it possible to pass in arguments that aren't the properties object (such that additional work could be done before rendering)? I tried, and the code failed to render anything on the screen. The changes I tried to make are shown below.

```
function Welcome(props, same) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name} and {same}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Please see the working sample of the code of yours I edited and posted. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings changes made

Comment: This is not possible, put you can pass anything as a prop, a function, an object or array. What is the use case you are looking for?

Comment: the use case in particular was thought of when I thought of this question. I was just curious.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a working sample of react code using cdn. Hope it helps :)

```
<div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
    function Welcome(props) {
      return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
    }

    const element = <Welcome name="Johnson" />;
    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
    </script>
```

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings: I just added the cdn to show the user that the code user posted is working and asked the user to show the error :).

Comment: You can easily do that with a Javascript Snippet. But this unfortunately is not an answer

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings: Do what with a javascript snippet ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: HTML/Javascript option available on answer panel. This can be used for the OP can run the code on SO. But unfortunately that can't be counted as an answer either

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings: I think the user is asking about using ReactJS and not HTML/JS. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49583944/4374566) is an example of how Javascript snippet can be used for React

Comment: I think there is miscommunication on the terms we have been using :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172326/discussion-between-boy-with-silver-wings-and-john-sam).