# Why do I always delete the first element while I am trying to delete others?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am trying to write a function which can delete the component I selected and show the result after the deletion inside the search box. However, when I was deleting the other items, it will always delete the first one also.

Here is the higher order component which contains the search box component

```
export default class Tagsearch extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hitsDisplay:false,
      inputContent:"",
      tags:[]
    };
  }

  handleRemoveItem = (index) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      tags: state.tags.filter((tag, i) => i !== index)
    }));
  }

  handleSelect = value => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      tags:[...prevState.tags, value]
    }));
    this.setState({ selected:true })
  }

  openDisplay = () => {
    this.setState({ hitsDisplay: true })
  }

  closeDisplay = () => {
    this.setState({ hitsDisplay: false })
  }

  render() {

    let result = (
      <div className="container-fluid" id="results">

      </div>
    )

    if (this.state.hitsDisplay) {
      result = (
        <Flexbox 
          flexDirection="column" 
          minHeight="100vh"
        >
          <div className="rows">
            <MyHits handleSelect={this.handleSelect}/>
          </div>

        </Flexbox>
      )
    }

  return (
      <InstantSearch
        appId="********"
        apiKey="**************************"
        indexName="tags"
      >
        <CustomSearchBox
          handleRemoveItem={this.handleRemoveItem}
          tags={this.state.tags}
          styles={styles}
          openDisplay={this.openDisplay}
          closeDisplay={this.closeDisplay}
        />
        {result}

      </InstantSearch>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the search box component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connectSearchBox } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const CustomSearchBox = ({ currentRefinement, refine, openDisplay, closeDisplay, styles, tags, handleRemoveItem, ...props }) => {
  const handleChange = (e, refine) => {
    const value = e.target.value
    refine(value)
    if (value !== "") {
      openDisplay();
    } else {
      closeDisplay();
    }
  }

  let inputTags = (
    tags.map((tag, i) => 
      <li key={i} style={styles.items}>
        {tag}
        <button
          onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(i)}
        >
          (x)
        </button>
      </li>
    )
  )

  return (
    <label>
      <ul style={styles.container}>
        {inputTags}
        <input
          style={styles.input}
          type="text"
          value={currentRefinement}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, refine)}
        />
      </ul>
    </label>
  )
}

export default connectSearchBox(CustomSearchBox);
```

I just wanted to delete the element which I press the button. So if I press the third delete button, the third element will be deleted and the first will persist.

I map my array in lower level component and pass the target to the higher level component. Even if I pass the name of the target itself instead of the index, it will delete the both the target and the first element. Compare to the possible duplicate question, its problem is deleting the last one, but mine will delete both the first one and the target one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list items are not deleting properly (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581586/list-items-are-not-deleting-properly-react)

Comment: I don't think the answer to the problem can solve my problem.